# angularjs $timeout without delay parameters reason

Tags: angularjs

In a few script I can find for instance

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.my = 1;            
});
```

instead of simply

```
$scope.my = 1;
```

What's the purpose to call $timeout without delay?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is a hack. :)  But usually the intention is to wait until the end of the `$digest` cycle and then set `$scope.my` to `1`.  Timeouts are called after all watches are done.

Comment: Davin, could you explain WHY it is a hack? Maybe provide an example of when it might be used and what the ACTUAL IDEAL solution would be? I notice it is quite prevalent in a project at work, and I understand what it fixes, but I can't quite figure out what a better solution would be.

Comment: Exemple : I have a click event which trigger an apply on the current scope and I have a watcher which triggers the same click event. I had to make a condition to not reload the apply call into the event and a timeout into the watcher to wait the end of the digest cycle (due to apply() called in the event). I'll post the code when soon.