# $digest already in progress when calling $rootScope.$apply() in quick succession

Tags: angularjs, events, location, rootscope, angularjs-digest

So I have an AngularJS service listening for some events. On the handling of these events I need to call different controllers and ultimately load a new view. In one event handler I am using $location.path() then calling $rootScope.apply() to trigger the routing to the controller. This works fine for that event, but in others I get the following error: `$rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress`. I'm guessing that it works in the first scenario because $rootScope.apply() is called from another callback function inside the listener function, where as the other handlers try to call it just from the event listener function.

```
//angular service

$rootScope.$on('MY_EVENT', function (event, msg) {
    MyClass.doSomething(msg, function (response) {
        $location.path("/view1");
        $rootScope.$apply();        //WORKS FINE
    });
});


$rootScope.$on('MY_OTHER_EVENT', function (event, msg) {
    $location.path("/view2");
    $rootScope.$apply();           //ERROR
});
```

How can I get it to work for all event handlers?

[plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vYwENCMBhfI1lhphCR5I)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that it's performing `$digest` on `$rootScope` twice in quick succession and it throws the error when there's an overlap. To get around this, you can simply wrap both calls to `$location.path()` in `$timeout`, as you have done the first time in your plnkr example. This will force it to wait for the `$digest` cycle to complete.

You may also remove the explicit calls to `$rootScope.$apply()`.

```
$rootScope.$on('FIRST_EVENT', function(event, msg) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $location.path("/view1");
  });
});

$rootScope.$on('SECOND_EVENT', function(event, msg) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $location.path("/view2");
  });
});
```

**Note:**

This code is based on the plnkr example, which is slightly different than the code in the original post.

**Reference:**

[wait for end of $digest cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610450/angulajs-angularjs-timeout-without-delay-parameters-reason)

Comment: I tried that with no luck. The routing is not triggered at any point.

Comment: Can you create an example jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Sure. Before I do that let me also mention that MY_EVENT is always triggered prior to MY_OTHER_EVENT. The time between the two events is an indeterminate.

Comment: Ok. I think if you can create an example that replicates this it will help myself/others identify the problem.